# How to de-obfuscate sssd.conf password?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ldap, sssd

I have inherited a number of EC2 instances with Centos that authenticate users against AWS Directory Service through LDAP. Now I need to run some manual queries with `ldapsearch` using the same account to debug some authentication problems. However the password is encrypted in the config, like this:

```
[sssd]
domains = LDAP
services = nss, pam

[domain/LDAP]
id_provider = ldap
cache_credentials = True

ldap_schema = AD
ldap_uri = ldaps://...
ldap_search_base = ...
ldap_default_bind_dn = ...
ldap_default_authtok = AAAQAB3QDeZ7+...cBSpT0ZABu4AAQID
ldap_default_authtok_type = obfuscated_password
```

Is there any way to decrypt / de-obfuscate the `ldap_default_authtok`? I don't want to change it in AD because it's being used on many servers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I happened to write a small script that decrypts these passwords about a year ago.

Interestingly the *SSS* developers went to great lengths with the obfuscation algorithm, using *AES-256* for example, yet in the end it's still easily decipherable because they bundle the randomly generated *encryption key* in the encoded string. Weird.

I put it on GitHub for you: https://github.com/mludvig/sss_deobfuscate

Usage is simple:

```
$ ./sss_deobfuscate AAAQABagVAjf9KgUyIxTw3A+HUfbig7N1+L0qtY4xAULt2GYHFc1B3CBWGAE9ArooklBkpxQtROiyCGDQH+VzLHYmiIAAQID
Decoded password: Passw0rd
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I created a python package (library and cli) that solves this task and added answer below with additional details. https://github.com/jteppinette/python-sssd-ldap-auth

Answer (score 3):

@MLu's answer will get the job done but I'll add some commentary.

It's a shame the devs called the methods `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` since they do no such thing.

If you look at the source for the python module (`src/python/pysss.c`) there is a `pysss.password.decrypt()` method but it is surrounded by `#if 0..#endif`. If those (and the corresponding `#if 0..#endif` around the c-python linkage) are removed and the source is recompiled `decrypt()` can be called. E.g.:

```
import pysss

password = 'swordfish'
print(password)

obfobj = pysss.password()
obfpwd = obfobj.encrypt(password, obfobj.AES_256)
print(obfpwd)

decrypted_password = obfobj.decrypt(obfpwd)
print(decrypted_password)
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jteppinette/python-sssd-ldap-auth

I created a python package based on @MLu's work.

---

## Install

```sh
$ pip install sssdldapauth
```

## Usage

**CLI**

```sh
$ sssdldapauth deobfuscate <obfuscated_password>
<password>
```

**Library**

```py
from sssdldapauth import deobfuscate

password = deobfuscate("<obfuscated_password>")
```